# How to convert oracle date (dd.mm.yyyy) into SAS date (yymmdd6.) in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, sas

I need to convert date 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' into SAS date 'yymmdd6.' format using pl/sql as `put(Date, yymmdd6.)` using SAS macro.

Please, help me.

Comment: Could you clarify: you are in Oracle and need to output in SAS format ? Or you are in SAS and have input in Oracle format ?

Comment: also, please give an example of input and desired output. And specify their types (string, date, numeric)

Comment: @Alexander Malakhov: I'm in Oracle and I need to output in SAS format.

Comment: Then I don't understand what's wrong with my answer. Please, give an example

Comment: oh, I had wrong data, so I thought, that date has SAS specific format (difference between date and '31.12.1971' as I understand). You are right, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TO_CHAR( date_var, 'YYMMDD') ?

Comment: no, in SAS date has specific format. See: [Example 2](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000199354.htm)